Singular integral equation of the first kind with 1/sinh(x-y) kernel
I'm having some problems solving a singular integral equation
$g(x) = \int_{-\infty}^a dy \frac{1}{\sinh(x-y)} f(y) $
where $g(x) = e^{-x/2}$ in one case and also $g(x) = \cosh(x)$ in another case.
I tried to put this integral equation in a Cauchy form with kernel 1/(x-y) by substitution $x=\tanh z$ and $y=\tanh w$ but I couldn't solve it. I think the solution will have some square root terms.
Has anyone seen this equation in some book or other references? It could be very useful.
Thanks.

Is the upper limit of integration an arbitrary $a$?

I would like to know the solution for arbitrary, finite, real a.
